# Sonatype Nexus - Can I manually compact blob store?

Tags: centos7, nexus, blobstore, sonatype, nexus3

My disk is full on my CENTOS7 box. There is nothing to delete to free up some space securely without the risk of corrupting something.

Since the disk is full, OrientDB has switched to read-only mode so I can't create a Compact Blob Store task to clean up disk space. I need to do this manually.

- No, I can't add extra disk space.

Would that be possible to find the source for "compact blob store" task and run it manually/externally?

Nexus version is 3.12.1-01

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can run task manually, login to nexus portal as admin

go to setting -> tasks -> create task (Admin - Compact blob store)

then you can click button run task manually[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to execute tasks without NXRM running.

However, what the compact blob store task does is takes items that have been soft deleted and remove them from your blobstore.  If you are blocked, I imagine it'd be possible to write a script to find these and delete them (or even do it manually).

See this example properties file (deleted=true):

> ## 2018-09-11 18:55:59,354-0400
>
> ## Tue Sep 11 18:55:59 EDT 2018
>
> deleted=true
> @BlobStore.created-by=admin
> creationTime=1536617858040
> @BlobStore.created-by-ip=127.0.0.1
> @BlobStore.content-type=text/plain
> sha1=05f4f83e8cc91e39e0d697c264ce7c732ac98849
> @BlobStore.blob-name=ticketlist.txt
> deletedReason=Deleting asset AttachedEntityId{asset->#49:1}
> @Bucket.repo-name=rawhosted1
> size=1772

Answer (score 1):

For more information on how NXRM does it you can take a look at the source code for FileBlobStore#compact here https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/cf2626d4a0deb2181ce4f1c8ea1f434231ba962e/components/nexus-blobstore-file/src/main/java/org/sonatype/nexus/blobstore/file/FileBlobStore.java#L553

You'll notice it makes use of a deleted file index to prevent you having to traverse the entire store.